# Guidance on how to setup the basic “Components” example from the official EmberJS homepage

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, templates, ember.js

My background is in old-school web development and LAMP stack development mixed with Linux server administration. Meaning I can code HTML, PHP, CSS and JavsScript—as well as manage a Linux server—with ease. But have decided I need to be a bit “modern” as far as web client side technology goes and am teaching myself EmberJS on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 machine. Core versions are as follows:

- **Ember CLI version:** 1.13.12
- **Node JS version:** 4.2.2
- **NPM (Node Package Manager) version:** 2.14.10
- **Watchman:** 4.1.0

The basic “Auto-Updating Handlebars Templates” example on the official EmberJS site works, but I am lost on [the “Components” example on the EmberJS homepage](http://emberjs.com/).

My process so far as been to init a new app like this:

```
ember new new-app
```

Then once that is done and the folder structure is built, I am simply creating new documents based on that [“Components” example](http://emberjs.com/) as follows; see screenshot for an example:

- `app/templates/components/gravatar-image.js`
- `app/templates/application.hbs`
- `app/templates/components/gravatar-image.hbs`

[image: Screenshot of my EmberJS example test app.]

Since I am new to EmberJS I am *assuming* this is the proper folder structure for this simple app example since `templates/application.hbs` is the only place I am seeing `application.hbs` installed and all of the paths on that simple homepage example are relative to some root, correct? But when I attempt to run it like this:

```
ember serve
```

It consistently fails with the following error:

```
version: 1.13.12
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '/path/to/new-app/tmp/template_compiler-input_base_path-97V11oKY.tmp/0/ember-sandbox/templates/components/gravatar-image.js' -> '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Ember-Sandbox/tmp/template_compiler-output_path-Tn5z8iTb.tmp/ember-sandbox/templates/components/gravatar-image.js'
```

Doing some basic online searches led me to believe it might require me to delete cached files and dependencies like this:

```
rm -rf node_modules tmp dist bower_components
```

And then reinstall them like this:

```
npm install && bower install
```

But even after that’s done, the same `EEXIST: file already exists, symlink…` pops up again.

What am I doing wrong? And what can I do to get this very basic example up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is that you have placed the `gravatar-image.js` file in the `templates/components` folder and it should be in the `components` folder. Inside `templates` folder goes only `*.hbs` (`templates` is used for route templates and `templates/components` is used for component templates).

There is another way of structuring the folders called `POD` in which you have a folder with the name of the component and its files inside. With your component would be like this:
`gravatar-image/component.js`
`gravatar-image/template.hbs`

Check [this tutorial](http://www.programwitherik.com/ember-pods/) if you are interested in using this `POD` structure.