# How to setup the “Loading Data from a Server” example on the EmberJS homepage within an Ember CLI structure?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I’m attempting to teach myself EmberJS basics using EmberCLI and such. Ran into [one folder structure hitch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33773650/117259) [which Henry Vonfire helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33774996/117259) understand and clear up.

Now that I have my “sea legs” a bit more stable, I am attempting to implement the “Loading Data from a Server” example [from the official EmberJS homepage](http://emberjs.com). I can get the app to run, but apparently no data is returned or rendered to the frontend despite the inspector clearly showing data is being properly fetched in my browser. Why is my “handlebars” template not parsing the data?

My environment is as follows:

- **Ember CLI version:** 1.13.12
- **Node JS version:** 4.2.2
- **NPM (Node Package Manager) version:** 2.14.10
- **Watchman:** 4.1.0

And my simple/humble controller structure is as follows:

- `app/routes/pull-requests.js`
- `app/templates/pull-requests.hbs`

And the content of each is as follows:

Contents of `app/routes/pull-requests.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('title', "Pull Requests");
  },
  activate: function() {
    document.title = "Pull Requests";
  },
  model: function() {
    return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/emberjs/ember.js/pulls').then(function(data) {
      return data.splice(0, 3);
    });
  }
});
```

Contents of `app/templates/pull-requests.hbs`:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<p>This is where we would be parsing raw pull request data.</p>

<h3>Last 3 Pull Requests to Ember.js</h3>
<ul>
{{#each model as |pr|}}
  <li>
    <div class="issue-number">#{{pr.number}}</div>
    <div class="issue-title">
      <a href={{pr.html_url}}>{{pr.title}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="author-name">
      Opened by <a href={{pr.head.user.html_url}}><strong>@{{pr.head.user.login}}</strong></a>
    </div>
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

Initially I had some CORS issues that were cleared up by setting the following `contentSecurityPolicy` block in `config/environment.js`:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': "'self'",
  'font-src': "'self'",
  'connect-src': "'self' https://api.github.com/",
  'img-src': "'self'",
  'style-src': "'self'",
  'media-src': "'self'"
},
```

Now the page simply loads without an error, but without iterating through the data. What’s up? Is this something that should be rejiggered into a code block in `models/pull-requests.js`? Or is there some syntax error with `app/templates/pull-requests.hbs` that is causing it to fail in some way? Or is it something else?

**UPDATE:** So [Kitler’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33798794/117259) unlocked the core reason this setup was failing. I accidentally overwrote `setupController` with my code logic without returning it’s data. And while I can indeed *override* it, I should have set `return this._super()`; by not doing that I was effectively wiping `model` from the rest of the router chain. But I am posting this update to show what I specifically adjusted in `app/routes/pull-requests.js` so anyone else may benefit from this solution.

The original `setupController` code I had was this:

```
setupController: function(controller) {
  controller.set('title', "Pull Requests");
},
```

Note how it only has the `controller` being passed to the interface? To make it work in my setup I had to add `model` and then `return this._super(controller, model)` like this:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('title', "Pull Requests");
  return this._super(controller, model);
},
```

With that set, it all works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here (most probably) is that you overwrite the `setupController` method and do not return super, what `setupController` does is set the model property on your controller.

What you would want to do is `return this._super(...arguments)` after `controller.set('title', "Pull Requests");`

Comment: You can still set things on the controller from `setupController` (you rarely need to do this) just remember to return super ^^

Comment: Nice, didnt even notice the missing super hook.